# Domain and range transformation

Tags: recurrence-relations

How can I solve this recurrence relation using Domain and Range transformations:

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
    n^2 a_n 
&=& 5(n-1)^2 a_{n-1} +2 \\
    a_0 
&=& 0 \\
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n^2a_n = x_n$. Then the given relation can be rewritten as $x_n = 5x_{n-1}+2$ or equivalently, $x_{n+1} -6x_{n}+5x_{n-1} = 0$. Then $x_n = c_15^n+c_2$ for constants $c_1, c_2$ determined by the initial conditions.

Then it is easy to get a closed form for $a_n$.

Comment: and so an = bn / n^2?
and it should be an = 2*5^n - 2 \n^2 ?

Comment: $a_n = x_n/n^2$.

Comment: yea I'm sorry I've missed the charachters.

Comment: I have a question, when you said equivalently how did you convert between the two equations?

Comment: So we have $x_n = 5x_{n-1}+2$. Shift the index up $1$ so $x_{n+1} = 5x_n+2$. Now subtract. Generally, you want to get rid of constants and get an equation only involving $x_i's$ so the characteristic polynomial becomes obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Use generating functions on the recurrence given by Sandeep Silval: Define $g(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} x_n z^n$, write the recurrence as:
$$
x_{n + 1} = 5 x_n + 2
$$
Multiply by $z^n$, sum over $n \ge 0$, and recognize the resulting sums:
$$
\frac{g(z) - x_0}{z} = 5 g(z) + \frac{2}{1 - z}
$$
As partial fractions:
$$
g(z) = \frac{1}{2 (1 - 5 z)} - \frac{1}{2 (1 - z)}
$$
thus:
\begin{align}
x_n
  &= \frac{5^n - 1}{2} \\
a_n
  &= \begin{cases}
       0                     & n = 0 \\
       \displaystyle \frac{5^n - 1}{2 n^2} & n > 0
     \end{cases}
\end{align}
\end{align}